# c# List been erased after each iteration

Tags: c#, list, class, constructor

I have a build a class and C'tor but from some reason it erase "**polygonList**"  after each iteration.
Generally its reads line from txt file which contains ID number and ID's of points.
must say I have class in similar form which works perfect.

any offers what I did wrong?

```
calling from main class:
tempPoly = new Polygon(totalLine,pointsList);
```

the class

```
public class Polygon
{
    public int polyID;
    public List<Polygon> polygonList = new List<Polygon>();
    public List<Point2D> vertexPoints = new List<Point2D>();

    public List<Point2D> VertexPoints
    {
        get { return vertexPoints; }
        set { vertexPoints = value; }
    }
    public Polygon(int polyID, List<Point2D> vertexPoints)
    {
        PolyID = polyID;
        VertexPoints = vertexPoints;
    }
    public Polygon(string[] line, List<Point2D> points)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < line.Length; k++)
        {
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                if (line[k] == point.PntID)
                {
                    VertexPoints.Add(point);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        polygonList.Add(new Polygon(int.Parse(line[0]), VertexPoints));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it have a break there?

Comment: @Robuust to stop iterating points if match found- then we go to next line

Comment: What do you mean by *each iteration*? You are adding only one polygon with first line to polygonList, and it's out of any iterations

Comment: Each iteration=new line from the txt files. The loop isn't quoted above@SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: @DimaB it's unclear what you are asking, and what is quoted loops. You are not adding items to polygonList in a loop. Also it's totally unclear how you are calling constructor. Variable names are not enough to understand what you are passing to constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're making a new - and then empty - `List<Polygon>` whenever you call one of `Polygon`s c'tors:

```
...
public List<Polygon> polygonList = new List<Polygon>();
public List<Point2D> vertexPoints = new List<Point2D>();
```

What you presumably want is a static list, that only exists once for all instances of the `Polygon` class. Leaving concurrency issues aside, you can do this:

```
public static List<Polygon> polygonList = new List<Polygon>();
public static List<Point2D> vertexPoints = new List<Point2D>();
```

This way, each instance of Polygon will write to the *same* list.

Answer (score 0):

If `totalLine` is of type int, then you are never calling the overload of constructor which adds item in 'polygonList'

Answer (score 0):

The list is "erased" every time you instantiate a new `Polygon` because `polygonList` is a field of `Polygon`.

```
polygonList.Add(new Polygon(int.Parse(line[0]), VertexPoints));
```

I'd expect something like:

```
public class Polygon
{
    public int polyID;
    public List<Point2D> vertexPoints = new List<Point2D>();
    // etc
}
```

And another object who's responsible of maintaining the list of `Polygon`s., e.g.:

```
public class Shape
{
    public List<Polygon> Polygons { get; private set}

    public Shape()
    {
        Polygons = = new List<Polygon>();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could make the List static just to get the code working. It would be a design flaw though.

```
 public static List<Polygon> Polygons = new List<Polygon>();
```